# Produce list of directories and files based on directory using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a massive list of files stored as paths in sql server.  It's easy enough to break the paths up into directories, however, I need to be able to present a list of all the files and folders on one level at a time.  SQL Server has some built in utilities to handle this for files local to the server, but they do not apply in this case.

Using a wildcard will return everything below the current directory, so I've discarded that.

Data:

```
C:\test\file.txt
C:\test\level2\file.txt
C:\test\level2\bc.txt
C:\test\level3\another.txt
```

Ideally, I'd like to pass in a folder, and see all the files and folders at that level.  Then I can present that in a treegrid control, but that part is outside the scope of the question.

Passing in 'C:\test\' should return:

```
C:\test\file.txt
C:\test\level2
C:\test\level3
```

Comment: `SELECT filename FROM datatable WHERE filename LIKE 'C:\test\%'` ?

Comment: `where Filename like @Path + '%' and Filename not like @Path + '%\%'`, i.e. everything at the desired level but not deeper, will get files but not folders. You could `union` a similar query to get folders.

Comment: HABO - thanks, this is getting me close!  Just have to figure out how to get directories only now.

Comment: `where Filename like @Path + '%\%' and Filename not like @Path + '%\%\%'` will get the next level, but nothing deeper. Strip everything from the last "\" on and what you have is the folder. (`Reverse()`, `CharIndex()`, `Len()` and `Left()`, combined with a little arithmetic, should do it.) If you use `union`, rather than `union all`, duplicates will be eliminated.

Comment: Nocturnal thought: Duplicates only need to be removed for the folders, (hopefully) not files. Using `distinct` on the query for folders and `union all` to combine the results should be more efficient.

Comment: where Filename like Path + '%\%' and Filename not like Path + '%\%\%' will only return folders that have exactly one more level of folders beneath it.  If there are additional levels of folders, then it does not return a result at all.  Passing in C:\test\ would return all 4 of the original results, but if there was a record for C:\test\leveltest\folder\file.txt, the folder C:\test\leveltest would not be returned as a result.

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If not, why not? (Accepting answers is part of the etiquette at StackOverflow. See [How Does Accepting An Answer Work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick. `OrderBy` is included to output file names before folder names. If you don't care about the order you can drop it and the `order by` clause.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Filenames as Table ( Filename VarChar(128) );
insert into @Filenames ( Filename ) values
  ( 'C:\test\file.txt' ), ( 'C:\test\level2\file.txt' ),
  ( 'C:\test\level2\bc.txt' ), ( 'C:\test\level3\another.txt' ),
  ( 'C:\test\level3\deeper\nothing.txt' );
select * from @Filenames;

declare @Path as VarChar(128) = 'C:\test\';

-- Get the files.
--   Filename longer than   @Path , but not containing an additional reverse solidus ('\').
select Filename, 1 as OrderBy
  from @Filenames
  where Filename like @Path + '%' and Filename not like @Path + '%\%'
union
-- Get the directories.
--   Filename longer than   @Path   and containing one additional reverse solidus ('\').
--   Locate the reverse solidus after the length of   @Path   and trim from that point onwards.
--   Since there may be many files in each folder, use   distinct   to get each folder once.
select distinct SubString( Filename, 1, CharIndex( '\', Filename, Len( @Path ) + 1 ) - 1 ), 2
  from @Filenames
  where Filename like @Path + '%\%' and Filename not like @Path + '%\%\%'
order by OrderBy, Filename;
```

Comment: Still working with this code - it returns folders only if they have files directory under them.  If there is a folder one more level down but no files, it returns nothing.

Comment: Do you mean that if you search for `'C:\foo\'` and there is an empty directory that matches, that directory is not output? If `'C:\foo\'`, with the trailing reverse solidus ("\"), is in the table then it will be selected. `'C:\foo'` is, by all appearances, a file with no type in the root folder and not a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
DECLARE @SearchDir VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @SearchDir = 'C:\test\' 

;WITH cte_TestData(Directory) AS
(
SELECT 'C:\test\file.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test2\file.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level2\bc.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level3\another.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level1\level2\bc.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level1\level2\level3\another.txt'
)
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('\', REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, '')) > 0
            THEN @SearchDir + LEFT(REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, ''), CHARINDEX('\', REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, '')) - 1)
        ELSE @SearchDir + REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, '')
        END
FROM cte_TestData
WHERE CHARINDEX(@SearchDir, Directory) > 0
    AND LEN(REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, '')) - LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Directory, @SearchDir, ''), '\', '')) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gouri's solution

```
DECLARE @SearchDir VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @SearchDir = 'C:\test\' 

;WITH cte_TestData(Directory) AS
(
SELECT 'C:\test\file.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test2\file.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level2\bc.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level3\another.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level1\level2\bc.txt' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C:\test\level1\level2\level3\another.txt'
)
SELECT * FROM cte_TestData
WHERE PATINDEX('%\%',REPLACE(Directory,@SearchDir,'')) = 0 --remove the @searchDir filter and what remains shouldnt containa backslash
```